# iOS7 : adding custom keyboard using inputview issue

Tags: iphone, ipad, keyboard, ios7, xcode5

I am using a custom keyboard and I am assigning that to inputView of the textfield.
But when the keyboard pops up, the rest of the view has a blur image(like in control center).

How to get rid of that effect?
I am using an xib for that custom keyboard whose size is same as the size of the window.

I loading the keyboard from .nib file.

Comment: could you provide a screenshot of the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Got a solution after some efforts on SO. Credits - khertz.

1. Define a custom subclass of UIView and specify that in your xib file
2. In this class override willMoveToSuperview: as follows

>

```
- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview    
{
        if (UIDevice.currentDevice.systemVersion.floatValue >= 7 &&
            newSuperview != nil)
        {
            CALayer *layer = newSuperview.layer;
            NSArray *subls = layer.sublayers;
            CALayer *blurLayer = [subls objectAtIndex:0];
            [blurLayer setOpacity:0];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked for me.